# Differential equation $x''+a(t)x'+b(t)x=0$ and wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let this differential equation :
>
> $$(H)\qquad x''+tx'-(1+t)x=0$$

As $\phi_a=e^t$, is a solution of $(H)$, we can deduce $\phi_b$ from the wronskian $W(t)=\begin{array}{|ll|}\phi_a(t)&\phi_b(t) \\ \phi_a'(t) & \phi_b'(t)\end{array}$
Thus $\left(\dfrac{\phi_b(t)}{\phi_a(t)}\right)'=\dfrac{W(t)}{(\phi_a(t))^2}$

As $W(t)$ is a solution of this equation $y'(t)=-t\cdot y(t)$ we have got $\displaystyle W(t)=\exp\bigg[-\int_{t_0}^t s\cdot ds\bigg]=e^{-t^2/2+t_0^2/2}=\lambda e^{-t^2/2}\qquad \lambda :=e^{t_0^2/2}$

So $\left(\dfrac{\phi_b(t)}{\phi_a(t)}\right)'=\dfrac{\lambda e^{-t^2/2}}{e^{2t}}=\lambda\cdot e^{-t^2/2-2t}$

And now I'am blocked, because if $\displaystyle \gamma(t)=\int\lambda\cdot e^{-t^2/2-2t}\cdot dt$, we have got $\dfrac{\phi_b(t)}{\phi_a(t)}=\gamma(t)$

So $\phi_b(t)=\phi_a(t)\cdot \gamma(t)$, **how to calculate** **$\gamma(t)$**???

Comment: The wronskian has dervitavies in it ..

Comment: @Isham May you be more explicit, please.

Comment: $W(t)=\begin{array}{|ll|}\phi_a(t)&\phi_b(t) \\ \phi_a(t) & \phi_b(t)\end{array}$ would just be $W(t)=0$. Instead, it should be $W(t)=\begin{array}{|ll|}\phi_a(t)&\phi_b(t) \\ \phi'_a(t) & \phi'_b(t)\end{array}$

Comment: You're done. $\phi_b(t) = e^t \int e^{-t^2/2-2t}\,dt$. That's as good as you can do (in terms of elementary functions). This **is** the answer - except for picking out a particular anitderivative, say $\phi_b(t) = e^t \int_0^t e^{-s^2-2s}\,ds$.

Comment: thanks, that is typo

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E(-s%5E2%2F2-2s)+from+s%3D0..t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_1=e^t$ is a solution than try $x=x_2e^t$

then it reduces to
$$x_2''+2x_2'+tx_2'=0$$
Substitute $u=x_2'$
$$u'+u(t+2)=0 \implies u=Ke^{-\frac {t^2}2-2t}$$
unfortunately it has a Gaussian like integral in it :
$$x_2(t)=K_1\int e^{-\frac {t^2}2-2t}+K_2$$
$$\boxed{x(t)=K_1e^t\int e^{-\frac {t^2}2-2t}+K_2e^t}$$